# Run python script from php

Tags: raspbian, python, bluetooth, php, web

Hello I want to run python script from php.
Python script is for reading sensor data.
This is python code and it's file name is sensor.py

```
import bluetooth
bd_addr="(mac address)"
port=1
sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((bd_addr.port))
data=""
while 1:
  try:
    data +=sock.recv(1024)
    data_end=data.find('\n')
    if data_end !=-1:
      rec data_end[:data_end]
      print data
      data=data[data_end+1:]
  except Keyboard Interrupt
    break
```

Now I can read sensor data if I run sensor.py and I want to display sensor data
on web server from php without database.

So I save php file in /var/www/html folder. It is code of file and file name is server.php

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('python /home/pi/sensor.py');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And I insert localhost/server.php on web browser but I can't check sensor data because of HTTP 500 ERROR. I thought it is because of permission. So I save another php file in /var/www/html to check my permission and it's file name is test.php

```
<?php
echo "HI";
echo date('y-m-d- H:i:s);
?>
```

And I insert localhost/test.php I can check HI and date. 
Then why I can't check sensor data if I insert localhost/sensor.php ?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is because your python script has an endless loop. Web servers impose a runtime limit on started scripts, most times in the range of seconds. [The PHP interpreter itself has another limit.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

You have to make your python script return within that timeframe. If you want to pass values to the browser window of the user continously, you have to run a Javascript in the browser which continously reloads a dedicated data page from the server. That way, the loop runs inside the browser and all is fine.

Also, there are no keyboard interrupts in a background process.

Comment: You might also want to note in your answer that [PHP has a configurable time limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) which might be the cause of the timeout and that it can be changed programmatically.

Comment: I've edited my answer.